# .then .done promises not working in durandal spa using knockout and js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application, q, durandal-2.0

I am working on a SPA developing in Durandal using Knockout jQuery and Require. My problem is when I make ajax calls to my API I don't actually get my data outside the .then statement(when I substitute my Get method with the line commented out below). However if i work with the current call I cannot use .then it gives me a type undefined error. I have looked at Durandal and they explain about using Q, I have it and referenced in my main. Not sure about the patches mentioned [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Q.html)

```
    var getSearchResult = function (dataHolder,text) {
            //return $.getJSON('/Api/Data/GetSearchItem/' + text).done();
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Api/Data/GetItem/' + text,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    dataHolder(data);
                    var check = dataHolder();
                    return dataHolder();
                },
                error: function (e) {
                }
            });
        };
```

I call the method like so:

```
        var search = function (searchText) {
            dtx.getSearchResult(searchResult, searchText).then(function () {//(searchResult is an observableArray
                searchFlag(true);
                var test = searchResult();//i get data here
                searchTxt(searchText);
            });
            var test1 = searchResult();//no data here
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you let `getSearchResult` return a promise?

```
var getSearchResult = function (dataHolder,text) {
        //return $.getJSON('/Api/Data/GetSearchItem/' + text).done();
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/Api/Data/GetItem/' + text,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).then(function(data) {
            dataHolder(data);
            var check = dataHolder();
            return dataHolder();
        });
    };
```

Then also let `search` return that some promise:

```
    var search = function (searchText) {
        return dtx.getSearchResult(searchResult, searchText).then(function (data) {//(searchResult is an observableArray
            searchFlag(true);
            var test = searchResult();//i get data here
            searchTxt(searchText);
        });
    };
```

Now you could call `search` as follows:

```
search(searchText).then(function(data) {

});
```

Comment: BTW, setting the `dataType` option is superfluous, so the Ajax call can be collapsed to `$.get('/Api/Data/GetItem/' + text)`. However care must be taken that `text` is URL-encoded properly. Not encoding it is a bug.

Comment: Oh and one more tip, since knockout observables are functions, they can be used directly as callbacks: `search(searchText).done(targetObservable)`.

Comment: this worked for me and @Jan Hommes answer below is also helpful. Thanks a lot and for the tips

Answer (score 1):

`getSearchResult` does not return a promise. So you can not use q.js promise. There are two ways to solve this issue.

1. The nice way: Implement your own promise resolver (see the q.js [documentation](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#getting-started). The **Deferreds** Part is what you are looking for)
2. The fast way: Add a callback to your `getSearchResult` function and use this:

   ```
   var getSearchResult = function (dataHolder,text, callback) {
           //return $.getJSON('/Api/Data/GetSearchItem/' + text).done();
           jQuery.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
               url: '/Api/Data/GetItem/' + text,
               type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                   callback(data);
               },
               error: function (e) {
               }
           });
       };
   ```

Then you can add a function as the callback:

```
        dtx.getSearchResult(searchResult, searchText, function (data) {
                //data contains the data from your ajax request.
                searchFlag(true);
                var test = searchResult();//i get data here
                searchTxt(searchText);
            });
```